# why does functions.config() return {}?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a firebase functions project. It’s giving me the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'privatekey' of undefined
```

The error is coming from this line here:

```
functions.config().blockchain.privatekey
```

Functions.config() is returning {} <— An empty object.

So my question is: why is it returning {}, and how can I fix it?

I’ve been able to solve similar problems with functions.config() in the past with this:

```
firebase functions:config:get > .runtimeconfig.json
```

But this isn’t working this time.

Is it something to do with how firebase init is configured? A node package?

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Where are you getting this?  In your deployed functions, or just in the emulator?

Comment: This is the emulator

Comment: Where is your `.runtimeconfig.json` folder located, and what is its contents?

Comment: It's under functions/. Same level as src/. It literally contains {}.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with the same folder structure and fixed it by changing directory (in PowerShell) into the "functions" folder and then running `firebase serve` from there.

Answer (score -1):

If anyone gets this error after creating the .runtimeconfig.json

Try checking the encoding of your file.  For me it was failing because the file was encoded as UTF-16 LE.  I changed it to UTF-8 and it works fine